# Validar CEP em Shell-Script

Tags: linux, regex, shell-script

Estou ingressando neste mundo de expressões regulares, estou com uma dúvida, eu li sobre os metacaracteres, etc. Bom, estou tentando validar um CEP e estou usando o seguinte comando e não estou conseguindo..eu já substituí o \d por [0-9] e tive sucesso, mas assim não estou conseguindo:

```
cat arquivo.txt | grep -E '^\d{5}[-]\d{3}'
```

No arquivo.txt tem a linha: 02954-852

Grato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obrigado por responderem, mas a solução mais simples era porque o \d não é reconhecido pelo parâmetro -E e sim pelo -P (Perl), o código ficou assim:

```
cat arquivo.txt | grep -P '^\d{5}-\d{3}$'
```

Mas muito obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 1):

Neste site abaixo tem bons exemplos.

http://www.terminalroot.com.br/2015/01/shell-script-validandotele.html

```
echo 'Informe o CEP';
read CEP
echo $CEP | egrep '^[0-9]{5}[-][0-9]{3}$' && echo -e '\033[01;32m Número válido! \033[0m' || echo -e '\033[01;31m NÃO é válido esse número.\033[0m'
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser que você não tenha fechado a expressão com cifrão:
Exemplo:

```
^\d{5}[-]\d{3}$
```